# How to know positive or negative phrase from qshere diagram?

Tags: qiskit

How to find out whether it is a positive or negative $\pi$ phrase between 00 and 11 from q-Sphere diagram?

[image: qshere]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The phase corresponding to the color of state $|11\rangle$ is $e^{i \pi}= -1$. So, it is a negative phase.

Generally, you plug in whatever angle the color of the state corresponds to into $e
^{i \theta}$ to get the phase of the state.

Answer (score 2):

As per @epelaaez's answer: the node color indicates the relative phase. However, there is a subtle point here.

As stated in this [page](https://egrettathula.wordpress.com/2021/07/10/quantum-state-visualization-using-qsphere/), if you run this code snippet

```
Ψ = [8 / 17, 0, 0, 15j / 17]
plot_state_qsphere(Ψ, show_state_phases = True)
```

the result will be

[image]

You can see that $|11⟩$ is displayed with phase = $0$ although it has a phase greater than zero. On the other hand, $|00⟩$ is displayed with a phase while it does not have one! This is because `plot_state_qsphere` function removes the phase from the term with maximum probability, and normalizes the phases of other terms accordingly.